# Select column based on Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe df with the following schema:

```
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- record_sales: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- record_marketing: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
```

and a map

```
typemap = Map("sales" -> "record_sales", "marketing" -> "record_marketing")
```

I want a new column "record" that is either the value of `record_sales` or `record_marketing` based on the value of `type`.

I've tried some variants of this:

```
val typeMapCol = typedLit(typemap)
val df2 = df.withColumn("record", col(typeMapCol(col("type"))))
```

But nothing has worked. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the map `typemap` and use `when` function to get `case/when` expressions depending on the value of `type` column:

```
val recordCol = typemap.map{case (k,v) => when(col("type") === k, col(v))}.toSeq

val df2 = df.withColumn("record", coalesce(recordCol: _*))
```